# Keras vgg transfer learning to save/load self defined fully connected layer

Tags: keras

In transfer learning it it possible to save fully connected layers only during training, and load it later for continued training? If possible, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, but I think this could solve your problem.

```py
import pickle

#set a name for all fully connected layers.
model.add(Dense(...,name='fc1'))
model.add(Dense(...,name='fc2'))
model.add(Dense(...,name='fc3'))


layers_to_save = ['fc1','fc2','fc3'] # add here any layer you want to save

# Save weights to a dictionary
weights_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer.get_weights()) for layer in model.layers if layer.name in layers_to_save]) 

with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(weights_dict, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)




# Load weights 
with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    weights_dict = pickle.load(handle)

for name in layers_to_save:
    model.get_layer(name).set_weights(weights_dict[name])
```

You can also check the second half of this [keras blog post](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) for another approach.

Comment: Thank you. I saw load top model, but I don't see how top model is saved. That's my question. If using 'from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint     ckp_callback = ModelCheckpoint(model_file, monitor="val_loss", save_best_only=True,  save_weights_only=True, mode='min')', all weights including vgg will be saved, right? How to just save top model?

Comment: Sorry, I`ve edited my post. In that blog post, first, you need to save bottleneck features(output of last convolutional layer), then train a FC model with them. That could be a good idea in some situation.